# C# Winchart configuration, adding more lines

Tags: c#

I am having some trouble with my C# chart.

I want to create a winnings chart.

**This chart is what I want to create:**
[image: Winning graph]

I currently have this:
[image: My graph]

```
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "$ USD";
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -1;
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1;
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Tourneys";
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
WinChart.Series[0].Points.Add(0);
WinChart.Series[0].Points.Add(0.10);
WinChart.Series[0].Points.Add(0.20);
WinChart.Series[0].Points.Add(0.30);
WinChart.Series[0].Points.Add(-0.50);
WinChart.Series[0].Points.Add(-0.60);
WinChart.Series[0].Points.Add(-0.70);
```

How can I make it start at the coordinates 0,0 and how do I make a middle line that is $0 ?

Documentation link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.aspx

Comment: you could change your scale to have a line for $0, also, `WinChart.Series.Add` to add a new line then repeat the last to lines of your code there

Comment: @czifro I don't know where to do that, do you?

Comment: have you considered looking at the documentation for WinChart

Comment: @czifro Yes I am. But I am not quite sure what to look for.

Comment: Add a link to the documentation to WinChart to your answer so that people can take a look

Comment: to change the scale do `WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 0.02;` this should add a line at $0.00

Comment: just keep adding points to `Series[0]` this should get you the graph you want

Comment: is WinChart a class that you have defined? if so, is Series a SeriesCollection object?

Comment: @czifro WinChart is a Control.

Comment: @czifro Can I make it have 7 lines instead of 6 so it will automaticly create a $0 line?\

Comment: I'm going to post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume some thing. WinChart is probably inheriting from Chart:

```
public class WinChart : Chart { }
```

and that ChartAreas is a ChartAreaCollection object and the same with Series

So I would do something like:

```
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "$ USD";
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -1;
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1;
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 0.2;   // adjusts y axis scale
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Tourneys";
WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;

Series series = new Series();
series.Points.Add(0,0);
...
series.Points.Add(5, 1.05);
WinChart.Series.Add(series);
//repeat last five lines to add second line to graph
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you perhaps also know how I make all lines short except for the $0 line?

Comment: please note I fixed a bug in the if statement, was `==` and is now `!=`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. "MessageBox.Show(WinChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Count.ToString());" Gives me 0.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have never used this api before, I was just ready the documentation. I suggest to look at the documentation as to how to change the line on a chart. if you figure it out, I suggest revising your question to show it